# Having trouble accessing redux store properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I'm trying to create a edit form for a list using the MERN stack. I am trying to populate the input fields in the form with the dynamic information from my redux store. I believe I have access to it, but it's now showing. I think it has something to do with my reducer or action logic.

**ClientEditModal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { editClient } from "../actions/clientActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ClientEditModal extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.editClient();
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal,
    });
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Close modal
    this.toggle();
  };

  render() {
    const { clients } = this.props.client;
    return (
      // Split button into separate component
      <div>
        <Button
          color="dark"
          style={{ marginBottom: "2rem", marginLeft: "1rem" }}
          onClick={this.toggle}
        >
          Edit
        </Button>

        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}> Edit</ModalHeader>

          <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="name"> Name </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  id="client"
                  value={clients.name}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                ></Input>
                <Label for="email"> Email </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="email"
                  id="client"
                  value={clients.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                ></Input>
                <Label for="number"> Number </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="number"
                  id="number"
                  value={clients.number}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                ></Input>
                <Button color="dark" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} block>
                  Submit Client Edit
                </Button>
              </FormGroup>
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ClientEditModal.propTypes = {
  editClient: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { editClient })(ClientEditModal);
```

**clientActions.js -- editClient**

```
export const editClient = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.put(`/api/clients/${id}`).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: EDIT_CLIENT,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
```

**clientReducer.js -- EDIT_CLIENT**

```
    case EDIT_CLIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        clients: [action.payload, ...state.clients],
      };
```

Comment: Did you ever connect your component to the store using react-redux's connect HOC.

Comment: import {connect } from "react-redux";   ?

Comment: Make sure you've mapped state to props in your ClientEditModal.js and connected the component using redux's connect HOC.

It would also be helpful in your question to mention exactly what is happening, other than simply saying that it's "not showing". Do you get any error messages, and if so, what are they?

Comment: const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
});

Comment: No error messages. Just the empty fields. So it's appears as though it works, but it's not rendering anything.

Comment: Have you checked the API endpoint as well? Either with Postman, or maybe trying console.log(res.data) inside your action. That would verify that you're really getting the data you are expecting.

Comment: @TaylorPhelps You mention `client: state.client` but in your reducer your state is `clients`. Try using `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ client: state.clients });`.

Comment: Can you please post the full code of `ClientEditModal`? It's possible you're not exporting a `connect`ed [version](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013/) of your component.

Comment: I have edited the original post. The comments won't let me post that much text.